# Designing a virtual machine with JIT compilation

Tags: compilation, language-agnostic, jit, language-design

I'm writing a virtual machine for a dynamically typed interpreted language that I'm creating, i thought of JIT and if it will be worth it to add it, the design i was having in mind is to have it embedded in the normal VM somewhere because like you know JITs aren't portable so i might not have all backends and would like to still reuse the normal VM and disable JIT with a simple #define flag, i just need a little design advices on how would this go, do i have to jit compile all instructions to machine code or what i was having in mind was something like a "partial jit" to jit compile a few performance critical instructions but then i don't know how would that work, how would it interfer with other instructions that aren't jit compiled and another question that comes up in my mind is how would i even represent types and all that on assembly level, overall I'm a total noob in jit compilers and need someone to guide to the right path, What do other VMs like JVM and LuaJIT do in this case?